# Additional Linebreak in Wordpress post overview

Tags: php, wordpress

i observe the following behaviour and i can't figure out where it comes from.
I use Wordpress 5.6, everything up-to-date.

On my Homepage i have a post overview about different blog posts. Each of them contains a Read more element after the second paragraph.
If i view the full article i have the following HTML generated:
[image: full article]

=> As you can see there is a div, followed by a p element and then the more span.

On my start page however i get the following:
[image: additional linebreak]

=> There is an additional line break. **I'd like to get rid of it.**

My theme has a loop-blog.php which just calls the wordpress function `the_content`:

```
        <!-- BEGIN .article -->
        <div class="article">
            <?php the_content( esc_html__( 'Read More', 'natural-lite' )); ?>
        <!-- END .article -->
```

I tried to use the strip_teaser variable from the [Wordpress docu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/), but it doesnt affect the output at all. But the 
 tag has to come from the wordpress function itself, because the theme does not add anything there (see picture 2 for the END .article comment after the `<br>`)
But within the source code of [get_the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) i can't find the `<br>`

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way I stumbled on, was to undisplay it via CSS.

```
.blog-holder .article br {
    display:none; 
}
```

Not totally the solution I had in mind, but i can live with it for now. Any input on the original question still appreciated, as I'd like to understand where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see this line break is because of wordpress text editor. It adds the line break if the text is not given in div's and you use multiple paragraphs. So in order to avoid this issue try to add your text in div with some classname like "post__description__text".